# Excel LOOKUP returns 3.33333E-06

Tags: excel-formula

I have the following formula in W407 and it returns 3.33333333333333E-06.

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/INDEX(SUBTOTAL(2,OFFSET($A5,ROW($A5:$A400)-ROW($A5),0))*W5:W400,0))
```

The "SUBTOTAL(2,...)" function returns an array with a bunch of 0 and 1, 0 for invisible cells and 1 for visible cells. In this particular case, only A182 to A199 are visible. So, it returns an array with 396 elements, in which element 177 to 194 has a value of 1, the rest 0.

In W5:W400, only W199 (element 194) has a value of 300,000, the rest 0.

The INDEX function multiplies these two arrays element by element, giving an array with 396 elements. Since in the second array, only element 194 is not 0, the resulting array is a 0 array except element 194, which is 300,000.

Now, why does LOOKUP returns 3.33333333333333E-06?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So your formula is `=LOOKUP(2,1/300000)`

1/300,000 is 3.33333E-06 and, from the [Office docs](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/lookup-function-446d94af-663b-451d-8251-369d5e3864cb):

> If the LOOKUP function can't find the lookup_value, the function matches the largest value in lookup_vector that is less than or equal to lookup_value.

3.33333E-06 is 0.00000333333, which is definitely smaller than 2. As it's the only element in the array which is no-zero, that's what is returned.